# Withdraw US J1 visa application

Tags: visas, usa, j1-visas, applications

When you withdraw a J1 US visa application, is it considered as a refused visa?

If not, should I still mention it in my future US visa applications?

Comment: in general withdrawing (a decision on your part) doesn't count as a refusal, even if your motivation for withdrawing was them telling you that you would probably be refused. However, you should confirm this with whoever you have been applying to. It's important to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I contacted [IEP](http://www.iep.com.au/) who I used for my J1 Visa.  They deal with thousands of J1 visas a year, and confirmed that:

> Hi, no it wouldn’t be considered refused if they cancelled it.

Given they have students and others applying and changing degrees and getting jobs and more, I guarantee that they've dealt with it before (I used them 14 years ago), so they're a good authority on the matter.

As it's not a refusal, you won't need to declare it in any future applications, unless SPECIFICALLY asked about, obviously - don't lie if a border agent asks if you've ever applied for one in the past.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I haven't yet withdrawn it. I was supposed to go to US for research and applied for J1 but later had to drop my plan and asked for my passport to be returned without withdrawing the application. The application will remain open for an year after which it will be automatically cancelled/withdrawn.